# deploy portlets liferay 6.1 ga2 with jboss eap 6

Tags: deployment, jboss, liferay-6

I am trying to deploy a Liferay portlet to liferay 6.1 GA2. I am not an technical person, but I want to learn more about it. I have the following ERROR in the log:

```
13:40:45,016 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component com.liferay.taglib.ui.TabsTag due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.taglib.ui.TabsTag from [Module "deployment.list-portlet.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:78) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

13:40:45,057 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 189) JBAS018210: Register web context: /list-portlet
13:40:45,059 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/list-portlet]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 189) JBWEB000285: Error configuring application listener of class com.liferay.portal.kernel.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.list-portlet.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:74) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3294) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

13:40:45,060 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/list-portlet]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 189) JBWEB000286: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
13:40:45,060 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 189) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /list-portlet start, will stop it
13:40:45,060 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 189) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./list-portlet: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./list-portlet: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93)
    ... 7 more

13:40:45,264 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "list-portlet.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./list-portlet" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./list-portlet: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
13:40:45,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment list-portlet.war (runtime-name: list-portlet.war) in 43ms
```

Does somebody know how I can fix this problem?